# router-outlet not working my component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

I try to learn angular 2, to redesigning my personal website, but i have a problem, my application not load my component when i go in the route appropriate with the click in my navigation bar.

In my navbar.html i have 2 link :

```
        <li><a [routerLink]="['Home']"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['Langages']">Langages</a></li>
```

and i declare my route in my app.component.ts in @RouteConfig :

```
    {path: '/', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/langages', name: 'Langages', component: LangagesComponent},
```

and in my app.component.ts i have a template with a  to view my navigation bar and below i add a tag  to see my HomeComponent and if i switch page i see my LangagesComponent and not HomeComponent... so for this moment, i don't see HomeComponent and other component.

P.S : in my LangagesComponent i have :

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    templateUrl: "./dev/langages/langages.html"
})

export class LangagesComponent {}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`name` in routes is not supported (that was removed more than 1/2 year ago)

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['/']"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
<li><a [routerLink]="['/langages']">Langages</a></li>
```

```
{path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
{path: 'langages', component: LangagesComponent},
```

`path` in route configuration must not contain a leading `/`. 
In `routerLink` or `router.navigateByUrl()` a leading `/` indicates an absolute path, while without `/` the path is assumed to be relative.

There is also no `@RouteConfig` anymore (except when you use Dart instead of TS)

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html for more details.

Comment: I learn Angular 2 with this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fyfY5aqbLNI&list=PL55RiY5tL51olfU2IEqr455EYLkrhmh3n&index=2 so i have a URL change and i don't load my component if i go in /langages or my component HomeComponent in "/"

Comment: It was published in January 2016. This was about beta.1 times https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta1-catamorphic-involution-2016-01-08 Check yourself what changed since then.

Answer (score 1):

`name` and `useAsDefault(not sure)` were removed long back.
Now you should setup your routes as follow,

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: "home", component: HomeComponent},    
{ path: 'language',  component: LangagesComponent },
```

.HTML

```
<li><a routerLink="home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
<li><a routerLink="language">Langages</a></li>
```

**NOTE**: *Also make sure you have router-outlet placed somewhere to load dynamic views using router in HTML.*